# Ubuntu 17.10 keeps hibernating and cannot change settings

Tags: gnome, suspend, hibernate, 17.10

I have just upgraded to 17.10 on an Intel NUC DN2820FYKH.
Ubuntu keeps going asleep/hibernating every 5 minutes.

I have also gone into power management and changed Power Saving Blank Screen "5 minutes" to "Never" but i have no way to save it.. There is no "OK" button, nor any "Save" option. If i exit out, the settings just default to "5 minutes".
I am using Kodi on it, and it still hibernates even if there is something playing.

I have tried updating, but it says i am up to date.

Caffeine crashes every time, and Caffeine indicator does not seem to make any difference.

I have tried dconf-editor and i seem to be missing a lot of menu items. I do not have /apps/gnome-power-manager
Nor do i seem to have org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power

I have just noticed (as i am typing) i can also not add any items to favourites. It says that they have been added, but they do not appear in the menu.

Comment: It is possible the upgrade did not succeed; you may find that doing an clean install might help (but first run a Live USB/CD first to see if things run smoother than now).

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping not to have to do a clean install. I will tomorrow. I am (trying) to use it at the moment, running Kodi. Watching TV shows and having to press 'OK' on the remote every 3-4 minutes or it blacks out.. Frustrating.

Comment: UPDATE:Clean install, everything seems to be working perfectly.